# Can i use CloudKit with different iCloud Account

Tags: ios, database, xcode, icloud, cloudkit

I have a developer account and I'm developing an app for someone. I want him to be able to change datas in CloudKit so I want to use his iCloud account(He doesn't have a developer account, just personal account). However, i don't know how to differentiate my developer account and his iCloud account.

Thank You

Comment: What type of data (files, assets, strings, etc) will you be saving? Is this data private to each user of the app? Or is it shared between users?

Comment: @Thunk public data, only the app publisher will write data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `CloudKit`'s notion of public and private databases may achieve what you need to do. As a reference, I am referring to slide 45 in Apple's WWDC presentation on cloudkit (http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/208xx42tf0hw3vv/208/208_introducing_cloudkit.pdf)

Considering that each app has a container, and that container includes 1 public database (that all users of the app can access) plus a multitude of private databases (one per user), if the data you're storing isn't private, then consider storing it in the public database. You can modify it as needed during development by being logged into your `iCloud` account, and your client can modify it as well by being logged into his `iCloud` account. (Apple docs say the public database is stored in the App developer's iCloud space)

If you store the data in the private database, however, it will be written to an instance of the private database belonging to the currently signed-in user. So anything you write would go into a private database instance (which Apple docs says resides in each user's personal iCloud space) and anything he writes would go into his private database instance. Until recently, that was the end of the story. However, now, `cloudKit` supports `CKShare` which, in a nutshell, allows a user to grant access to specific shared items inside their private db. So you could still write the data to a private DB but allow access via a `CKshare`.

Finally, there's another option, but I don't recommend it. In the device settings, you can log out of `iCloud` and log back in as another user. In which, you're still developing on your device, but you're logged into iCloud as your client. This has many drawbacks, though. First and foremost, credential sharing is always a bad security practice. But, probably a more immediate consequence will be your device will no longer be sharing with/backing up to your `iCloud` account, but instead with the client's.

It's hard to give more specific advice without better understanding the scenarios you're implementing.

** **update based on OP's comment** **

I see now. Using the development cloudkit dashboard probably isn't going to work. AFAIK, you must log in with a development account, not just an iCloud account, to use the cloudkit dashboard. So your client won't be able to get in at all, anyway. You could add your client's email address as a member of your development team, which will let them log into your cloudkit dashboard; however, that also gives them access into portions of your iTunesConnect as well. And, it really won't scale to support additional users of your app.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Actually i'm developing an artist app for a musician. After i develop the app, s/he could give datas to the app (example new events). Cloudkit has a nice dashboard and i want him/her to use the dashboard to edit data (Because i believe that it is easy). I don't know if i can achieve this with ur recommendation?